# Editing template content from the dashboard screen in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, admin

I would like to set up a way to be able to edit content in my template form the wordpress dashboard or new admin page.

Something like creating input boxes on the dashboard, or on a new admin page, that would update specific content I have hard coded in my template.

I'm using a one page site (long scrolling), and would like to allow people to edit the separate content areas from an admin page.

(an existing plugin that does this would be fine too)

Thanks!

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish what you want. "do_action()" hooks that execute in the header after the body declaration, for example. Depends on the features and modifications you want to be programmable. An example would help.

Comment: hmm, not sure where to find an example.. Basically, If there could be a page in admin that I could have a text area for a user to edit that would replace text somewhere in my theme, that would be excellent!

Comment: It does not seem to be a hard task, as you describe it. But, it would be necessary to create a plugin to have access to admin backend. ¿Have you tried searching for the plugin within WP? There might be some out there.

Comment: I haven't found anything.. I have played with this, so I know how to create a page and add things to it. Just not sure how to create the form inputs that edit the text in my template..
http://colorlabsproject.com/tutorials/create-a-simple-wordpress-admin-panel-part-ii/